# Android Kitkat allows only swipe on 360 image

Tags: android, google-vr, 360-virtual-reality

I am trying to implement 360 image for android in my application. I was successful in viewing the 360 image in my app using this tutorial https://developers.google.com/vr/android/get-started#start_your_own_project. After that I have to cases with phones running on different android APIs:

1. I was running the app in a phone which is running API 19(Kitkat). I can only swipe the 360 image to view the other areas of the image.
2. I implement the app in my other phone which is running on Lollipop, the image rotates along with the movement of my phone and there is no swipe option in it.

So, my query is:

Is there a way to toggle between these two options of swiping the 360 image manually and automatically rotating the 360 image along with the movement of my phone or having both options of viewing the image in one screen?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be possible yet, based on currently available documentation. Depending on the device, the SDK allows you to swipe the image with your finger or rotate the view using the gyroscope, but not both.

**ORIGINAL**

Did you use the VR view? Based on [this post](https://support.google.com/cardboard/answer/6383058?p=vrview&rd=1) you can supposedly only do click and drag on a computer (browser), not Android.

Did you use a WebView for your swiping functionality?

Comment: Like I have mentioned its working smoothly on lollipop. I have used the google VR panoramic view widget. In my lollipop phone i have to move the phone around to see the 360 view whereas in my kitkat phone I have to drag (the drag is not smooth at all). I wanted to know if there was an option to have both drag and move option in one window.